# OLS vs regression / classfication tree

Tags: regression, cart

I am using regression tree to find the factors effecting food insecurity. I want to know how regression tree is better than OLS in terms of heterogeneity. Can anybody help?

Comment: This question is not clear. What do you mean by "how regression tree is better than OLS in terms of heterogeneity"?

Comment: I mean to say that OLS smooth out all heterogeneity in the sample data but regression tree can make small groups of homogenous characteristics and then give results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean but 1) OLS regression with no interaction terms, splines or polynomial terms gives you one type of best fit to your data: The best fit that is a straight line combination of the p various independent variables in a p-dimensional space. This may be what you mean by "smooth out all heterogeneity". Regression trees do not do this: Continuous IVs can be split at any point, so the relation between an IV and the DV can be nonlinear or even non-monotonic. 2) With more than one IV, regression trees automatically consider interactions, but they do so in ways that OLS regression cannot (at least not easily).

Comment: Thank you Peter Flom, Would you please help me to get some published reference for this?

Comment: I don't know of a specific reference that says both of these things. Any book on regression will say the first and any book on trees will say the second. E.g. [Breiman et al.](http://www.powells.com/biblio/62-9780412048418-1)